# error redirect to react after local auth with passport using node js express

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, passport-local

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/my8Xb.png) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFLK8.png)** hi every i have problem i cant redirect to my react app its redirect to html instend react route its shows error in inspect window network XHR :

```
cant get /login
```

, and the response headers : Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 , and status code : 304 Not Modified but when i click the request on inspect i get the react route / or /account/login what i have to do *

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    if (!user) { return res.redirect('/login'); }
    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
      if (err) { return next(err); }
      return res.redirect('/');
    });
  })(req, res, next);
});

app.get('/login',(req, res) => {
  if (req.user) {
    res.redirect ('/');
  }
  res.redirect ('/account/login');
};
```

Comment: can you clarify more on what you are trying to acheive

Comment: ok just min to fix

Comment: just left an answer so let me know if it helps

Comment: can you please  see the seconde pic i mean it shouldnot show html responce must redirect to react router

Comment: in the second pic if i clicked to localhost i nav to home route (react app) but i need if any one click signin and successfull signin  must navigate to route('/')

Comment: try using return res.redirect

Comment: i try no difference

Comment: have you tried the answer to specify the redirect route e.g res.redirect('localhost:3000/account/login')

Comment: yep doesnot work

Answer (score 1):

When using `res.redirect()` it redirects to the current domain it's on
 So Instead what you want do is

```
  const PROJECT_DOMAIN = 'https://myapp.com'; suppose your app is in production
 res.redirect(`${PROJECT_DOMAIN }/account/login`)
```